# Multiple socket.io connections

Tags: node.js, socket.io

For some reason, sometimes our socket.io connections do not close properly.
We can observe more than one socket.io connected to the same client.

[image]

Above is a screenshot from Firebug. The same behavior was observed in IE9 as well.
Probably a problem with our code but where should we start checking? Which configuration could be causing this?